# SQL XML add elements to root

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces

I have an XML that is being generated via SQL and the root looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89 
      ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
```

I want it to look like so:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89 
      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
```

Here is my SQL code:

```
DECLARE @persons XML = (
SELECT(
blah blah blah
)FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89'))
set @persons.modify('insert ( attribute ns1 {"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"}) into (/ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89)[1]')
    SELECT @persons
```

and it returns the first root, how do I get it return like the second root I showed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the namespaces using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`

Try this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i
                  ,DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays')
SELECT NULL
FOR XML PATH('ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89')
```

The result

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

Comment: but this adds attributes to all my nodes

Comment: @user979331 You are right. This is a well known issue for years... It's not a bug, but it's annoying. There's even a [Connect-article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements). There are several workarounds... If you show your query (the part, where's written *blah blah blah*, I could help you further... I'd suggest - as this answer solves the current question fully, to vote it up and accept it. Than start a new question *How can I avoid repeated namespaces?* and I'll pop up there soon.