# How can I add constants to my root in XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, root

This is my query that generates an XML:

```
SELECT [a]                             a
      ,[b]                             b
      ,[c]                             c
      ,[d]                             d
      ,[e]                             e
      ,[f]                             f
      ,[g]                             g
  FROM test
  ORDER BY 1
  FOR XML PATH('a'), ROOT('ROOT'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

The XML generated starts with this root:

`<ROOT xmlns:xsi="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">`

My goal is to have a root with more attributes

`<ROOT xmlns:xsi="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" cod_1="SIN_OPE" cod_2="08" num_reg="12" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.xsd">`

This attributes are like constants (thet are not columns from select) that I want to append to my root. They will be fixed, whatever will be the select

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I'm sorry but It's pretty difficult to focus the question; the idea is similar to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850463/sql-xml-add-elements-to-root) but with fixed attributes that don't need xmlns:xsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a conceptual example. Please give it a shot.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, city VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (city) VALUES
('Miami'),
('Orlando');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT 'SIN_OPE' AS [@cod_1], '08' AS [@cod_2], '12' AS [@num_reg]
    , 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.xsd' AS [@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation]
, (
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('root'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

**Output**

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" cod_1="SIN_OPE"
      cod_2="08" num_reg="12"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.xsd">
    <r>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <city>Miami</city>
    </r>
    <r>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <city>Orlando</city>
    </r>
</root>
```

Comment: @Fuboski, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote this suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali